# I can't apply click event when I press on a suggestion

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, typeahead.js

I am having hard times in being able to select inside a link function, in a directive, the child element containing the list of suggestions provided by typeahead on the fly. It is like they don't exist yet when I trying to intercept the click event (so the user choice it) and to remove the dim effect on the rest of the page.. I am using this as directive because it is in more than one in a single page.

Here below the code, I tried to make it working with jsfiddle without success. The part where I am having problems is when I try to select the div.tt-menu element:

```
$('div.tt-menu').click(function(e) {
```

The element must be the one belonging to a parent with a specific ID. Unfortunately the last element I can select is the input field with the typeahead class:

```
$('#' + idelement + ' .typeahead')
```

which doesn't have children! So I can't select the element containing the suggestions:

[image]

```
(function(angular) {
  var app = angular.module('pi.core');
  app.directive('piSearch', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        onChange: '&',
        records: '=',
        text: '@',
        dim: '@',
        classes: '@',
        searchicon: '@',
        imgclasses: '@',
        idelement: '@'
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller, transcludeFn) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
          scope.$watch('idelement', function() {
            var idelement = scope.idelement;

            scope.elementSelected = $('#' + idelement + ' .typeahead');
            scope.elementSelectedSingle = $('#' + idelement);
            console.log(scope.elementSelected);
            console.log(scope.elementSelectedSingle);

            var records = new Bloodhound({
              datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
              queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
              local: scope.records
            });

            var dim = false;
            if (scope.dim) dim = scope.dim == 'true';

            scope.elementSelected.typeahead(null, {
              name: 'data',
              limit: 10,
              source: records
            });

            scope.elementSelectedSingle.click(function(e) {
              e.stopPropagation();
              if (dim == true)
                scope.elementSelectedSingle.addClass('pi-search-dim');
            });

            $(document).on('click', function() {
              scope.elementSelectedSingle.removeClass('pi-search-dim');
            });

            $('div.tt-menu').click(function(e) {
              console.log(e);

              e.stopPropagation();
              scope.elementSelectedSingle.removeClass('pi-search-dim');
              //var newValue = $('input.pi-search')[1].value;

              //                            scope.searchValue = newValue;
              //                            scope.onChange({ search: scope.searchValue });
            });
          });
        });
      },
      controller: function($scope, $transclude) {},
      template:
        '<div id="{{idelement}}" class="form-group has-feedback pi-search-container pi-component-container"><input type="search" class="form-control pi-search typeahead {{classes}}" placeholder="{{text}}" ng-model="searchValue" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 100 }" ng-change="onChange({search: searchValue})"/><img src="{{searchicon}}" class="pi-search-search-icon {{imgclasses}}"></div>'
    };
  });
})(angular);
```

Comment: You should attach click event handler to your dropdown OR textfield, whatever you are using for typeahead plugin, and not on "tt-menu"

Comment: Hi Shaybi, unfortunately no dropdown here...only new divs created and destroyed on the fly by typeahead lib, except for the element div.tt-menu (which contain all suggestions)